# Create SOAP envelope of XML and send it as HttpWebRequest to WebService

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, soap

Dear community I'm trying to send this `SOAP Envelope` as `HttpWebRequest` via `Webservice`.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Body>
<StatusNespolehlivyPlatceRequest xmlns="http://adis.mfcr.cz/rozhraniCRPDPH/">
<dic>445522999</dic>
</StatusNespolehlivyPlatceRequest>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

How could I access the `WebService` parameters and create `HttpWebRequest` for given `WebService` please?

Thanks for your time and answers, I appreciate that so much.

Comment: Why do you want to deal with those SOAP stuff. Just open `Developer Command Prompt` and type `wsdl /namespace:Rozhrani  http://adisrws.mfcr.cz/adistc/axis2/services/rozhraniCRPDPH.rozhraniCRPDPHSOAP`. Tada your `rozhraniCRPDPH.cs` class is there. That is all.

Comment: Marek I suggest a completely different way which hides all those details from you. Just add the generated `.cs` file to your project and create your services as `Rozhrani.rozhraniCRPDPH srv = new Rozhrani.rozhraniCRPDPH();`. After that all you have to do is to invoke the methods. No SOAP, No Xml, No namespaces etc.

Comment: Hello I tried that but I got this error processing: `http://adisrws.mfcr.cz/adistc/cr2/services/rozhraniCRPDPH.rozhraniCRPDPHSOAP` Command wasn't successful HTTP 404: /adistc/cr2/services/rozhraniCRPDPH.rozhraniCRPDPHSOAP would you please propose me any help? Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: Marek Change to a directory where you have write access privilege. for example `c:\temp` `Documents And Settings` etc.